# How do I create a powershell script to set default file type (.ica specifically) to open with a .exe located in C:\program files (x86)\

Tags: powershell, remote-access, citrix, windows-scripting, default-programs

Users must install Citrix Connection Manager to work from home.

Often, their default program to open `.ICA` files is set to a browser or nothing at all.

Some users don't know how to do this and still have issues with a very thorough step-by-step guide. Once the user has installed the CCM, it's located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\wfcrun32.exe`.

Unable to find previous scripts that successfully complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

- The following uses `cmd.exe`'s internal [`assoc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) and [`ftype`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype) commands to associate `.ica` files with a self-created file type named `CitrixConnection`, which means that such files will open with the executable specified as part of the file-type definition.

  - As *internal* `cmd.exe` commands, they must be called via `cmd /c` from PowerShell.
- These commands require *elevation* to run, because they create *machine*-level (all-users) definitions.

  - It *is* possible to create *user*-level definitions, but doing so would require direct manipulation of the Windows registry.

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# NOTE: There must be NO SPACE before `&&`, as that space would
#       otherwise become part of the argument value (even with "..." quoting).
cmd /c @"
assoc .ica="CitrixConnection"&& ftype CitrixConnection="C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\wfcrun32.exe"
"@
```

Note the use of an (expandable) [*here-string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) so as to make use of *embedded* quoting easier.

---

To later *remove* these definitions, run:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# NOTE: There must be NO SPACE before `&`.
quoting).
cmd /c 'assoc .ica=& ftype CitrixConnection='
```